# Sonar Qube UI long to update

Tags: java, sonarqube

We have recently installed a SonarQube instance to check our source code. 
The codebase is pretty large, with more than 1 million lines of code.

We run sonar-runner automatically via Jenkins.

Now I get that the UI gets updates only after sonar-runner stores its results in the database. 
But it seems to really take ages sometimes, up to an hour after the success of sonar-runner before we are able to see anything coming in the UI.

So I have a couple questions, all related :

- Is there a way to see analysis that are still 'in the pipes'?
- Where can I see whether the conversion from database to the UI has failed?
- Is there a way to speed the process?

So if I summarize? How can I impact the sonar-runner to sonar UI latency?

I went through all the docs but couldn´t find much about this yet.

Thanks for the info,

Comment: Is that comment supposed to mean anything? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Is there a way to see analysis that are still 'in the pipes'?

Yes, log in as admin and go to Settings > System > Analysis report

> - Where can I see whether the conversion from database to the UI has failed?

have a look at the content of the "Current Activity" and "Past Reports" tabs

> - Is there a way to speed the process?

This is a very broad question which implies tones of different answers. It all depends on where time is spent. You may be CPU bound, or memory bound or database bound, ...

Having a look at the queue of report processing might give you a hint.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. I find the SonarQube quite difficult to get around, and didn´t know about some of those views. It is definitely gonna help.

Answer (score 0):

1 MLoc is not so huge. I run SonarQube thru sonar-runner+Jenkins, and when Jenkins indicates in the log that the analysis has been successful, I am able to see it in SonarQube's dashboard. So I would say your 'latency' is not normal.

Could you please precise your environment? Physical/virtual? OS? DB? SQ release? etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We´re running on a vmware environment, a virtual 64b centOS with 32Gb or RAM and with 8 cores. So it should be beefy enough. Running the latest 5.x SQ, with the equivalent runner. We´re using a MySQL db hosted on the machine directly. At least now I understand why I couldn´t find anything related to latency on the net.

Answer (score 0):

After loads of searching around,  I realized that for some reason sonarQube didn´t handle correctly the fact that I was running several sonar-runner analysis right after each other. 
After the ´Store results in database´ message, there are a couple seconds for which starting a new analysis will cause SonarQube GUI to not see the analysis.

Running analysis with a bit more time between them reduced the latecny by a great deal.

Due to the fact that Seb gave a lot of insight about SonarQube itself, I will accept his answer. It is also probably more fit to a general public and less specific to my situation.

Comment: seems you accepted your own answer contrary to your statement

Comment: Right, sorry. A combination from accepting using a phone in my bed and having a few beers beforehand. Thanks again for the help, SonarQube runs like a charm now :).